# Alternative To ChartView in QML

Tags: qt, qml

I'm Trying to create an AreaChart Using ChartView over a QApplication on Raspberry Pi But no matter how small or big the chart is, QApplication Increase Start Time of my App to Over 20 sec and after that about 5-10 sec to show chart.

is there any alternaive to ChartView to use on QML that use faster QT based Object(QGuiApplication,etc) ??

or is there any method to increase run time of QApplication (Beside what they said in [This](https://wiki.qt.io/Performance_Tip_Startup_Time))

QT Version = 5.11.3
any help would appreciated.

Comment: This looks like a wrong behavior. Once I used `ChartView` on Android device and it worked well. Did you try to run the app using QML profiler? Anyway, if your chart is not to complicated you always can draw it by yourswelf using either `Canvas` or custom `QQuickItem`/`QQuickPaintedItem` item.

Comment: No i have not tried QML profiler. But through debug steps it appears that Construction of QApplication is irrelevant to QML file. I found another 3rd party lib called QNite that uses QguiApplication.  Testing and soon will update my question